# How can I make mysql access public and not restricted only to localhost?

Tags: wordpress, amazon-web-services, phpmyadmin, bitnami

I'm trying to connect zapier to the mysql db installed with a bitnami wp site in aws, but it seems I cannot connect them if the access is only restricted to the localhost. Any idea on how to change this in order to make it work?

this is what my security group looks like:
https://pasteboard.co/HL2ALzP.png

this is what my registered targets look like:
https://pasteboard.co/HL2Aa1G.png

this is the info zapier asks for in order to connect:
https://pasteboard.co/HLa6HMC.png

Answer (score 0):

> WARNING: These instructions suppose an important security risk. I do not recommend to open your database to the public under any circumstances

You need to edit the `/opt/bitnami/mysql/my.cnf` and change

```
 bind-address=127.0.0.1
```

to

```
 bind-address=0.0.0.0
```

Then restart mysql

```
 sudo /opt/bitnami/ctlscript.sh restart mysql
```

Apart from that, you will need to open your firewall port in AWS. Here you have a guide for that

https://docs.bitnami.com/aws/faq/administration/use-firewall/

Comment: Hi, thank you for the answer. I already tried that and I still get this when trying to access it by going to mywebsite.com/phpmyadmin. "For security reasons, this URL is only accessible using localhost (127.0.0.1) as the hostname."

Comment: I see. For that you do not need to open mysql, but connect to phpmyadmin using this guide: https://docs.bitnami.com/aws/apps/wordpress/administration/access-phpmyadmin/